# Sparklyr "embedded nul in string" when collecting

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

In R I have a spark connection and a DataFrame as `ddf`.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(tidyverse)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "foo", version = "2.0.2")
ddf <- spark_read_parquet(sc, name='test', path="hdfs://localhost:9001/foo_parquet")
```

Since it's not a whole lot of rows I'd like to pull this into memory to apply some machine learning magic. However, it seems that certain rows cannot be collected.

```
df <- ddf %>% head %>% collect # works fine
df <- ddf %>% collect # doesn't work
```

The second line of code throws a `Error in rawToChar(raw) : embedded nul in string:` error. The column/row it fails on has some string data. Since `head %>% collect` works indicates that some rows seem to fail while others work as expected.

How can I work around this error, is there a way to clean up the error? What does the error actually mean?

Comment: What are the data types of the columns in Spark? And can you provide sample data?